# Selenium Switch Tabs

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, webdriverwait, window-handles

Since Firefox does not support Control + T anymore for the tab, I started using 
    driver.execute_script("window.open('URL', 'new_window')")

I am trying to display the title of the different tab I open and switch between them.  For the example below, I expect the output to be facebook, google and back to facebook. Right now the output is facebook, facebook and facebook.

I tried the answer from here but it also did not work: [Switch back to parent tab using selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880295/switch-back-to-parent-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")
print(driver.title)

driver.execute_script("window.open('http://google.com', 'new_window')")
print(driver.title)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
print(driver.title)
```

UPDATED:
I tried the follow code and it still did not work.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")
print(driver.title)
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]

driver.execute_script("window.open('http://google.com', 'new_window')")
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
print(driver.title)
```

Answer (score 5):

A few words about Tab/Window switching/handling:

- Always keep track of the *Parent Window* handle so you can traverse back later if required as per your usecase.
- Always use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) with [expected_conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) as [`number_of_windows_to_be(num_windows)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be) before switching between *Tabs/Windows*.
- Always keep track of the *Child Window* handles so you can traverse whenever required.
- Always use *WebDriverWait* with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`title_contains("partial_page_title")`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) before extracting the *Page Title*.
- Here is your own code with some minor tweaks mentioned above:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.facebook.com/")
  print("Initial Page Title is: %s" %driver.title)
  windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle
  driver.execute_script("window.open('http://google.com')")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  windows_after = driver.window_handles
  new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0]
  driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.title_contains("G"))
  print("Page Title after first window switching is: %s" %driver.title)
  driver.close()
  driver.switch_to.window(windows_before)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.title_contains("F"))
  print("Page Title after second window switching is: %s" %driver.title)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Initial Page Title is: Facebook – log in or sign up
  Page Title after first window switching is: Google
  Page Title after second window switching is: Facebook – log in or sign up
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`window.open` will open the link in a new tab. Selenium Firefox driver doesn't have the ability to switch between tabs as there is only one window handle for both of them (unlike Chrome which has 2). If you give the `window()` command 'specs' parameter with width and height it will open a new window and you will be able to switch.

After opening the new window the driver is still focused on the first one, you need to switch to the new window first.

```
size = driver.get_window_size();
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://google.com', 'new_window', 'height=argument[0], width=argument[1]')", size['height'], size['width'])
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
print(driver.title)
```

Comment: I am still not able to print the title of the second window after switching. Instead of printing facebook again, now it just doesn't display anything.

Comment: @tada23 Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `driver.getWindowHandles();` to get all windows and `driver.switchTo().window(handle);` to switch to required one.

Answer (score 0):

This command always takes you to the recently opened new tab in chrome. Tested on latest versions of Chrome and Pytest on mac.

```
selenium.switch_to.window(selenium.window_handles[-1])
```