# Selenium Python does not close the child window

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, window-handles

I have webpage which open new browser window on click. I am able to get 2 handles however driver.close() always closes the first/main window.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("file:///D:/blackhole/print.html")
han = driver.window_handles
print("handles:", han) # gets 1 handle
time.sleep(2)
click_btn = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Print')
click_btn.click()
han = driver.window_handles
print("handles:", han) # gets 2 handles
driver.switch_to_window = han[1] # first element is always first window handle
driver.close() # main window close
```

Below webpage code which invokes new window

```
<a href="print.html"  
onclick="window.open('popprint.html', 
                    'newwindow', 
                    'width=300,height=250'); 
        return false;"
>Print</a>
```

Same behaviour for Firefox as well.
Python 3.6.7

Comment: I just tried running one of the tests (`testShouldThrowNoSuchWindowExceptionOnAnyElementOperationIfAWindowIsClosed` in python bindings of Selenium. The test is passing. Please have a look at 

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/aed1c2ad01048753f55317685d28ab69e99e8bd5/py/test/selenium/webdriver/common/window_switching_tests.py#L116

Therefore, I feel that `driver.close()` is working fine.

Comment: I tested with Python 3.7.0 on Windows too. The above stated test works fine.

Comment: Yes it does. Main difference I have found it `switch_to_window` versus `switch_to.window()` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Selenium* is unable to close the *active window* i.e the **newly opened window** because practically you havn't switched to the *newly opened window* in a clean way.

### Solution

A few words about Tab/Window switching/handling:

- [`switch_to_window(window_name)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_window) is deprecated for quite some time now and you need to use [**`driver.switch_to.window`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to)
- Always keep track of the *Parent Window* handle so you can traverse back later if required as per your usecase.
- Always use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`number_of_windows_to_be(num_windows)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be) before switching between *Tabs/Windows*.
- Always keep track of the *Child Window* handles so you can traverse whenever required.
- Always use *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` as [`title_contains("partial_page_title")`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) before extracting the *Page Title*.
- Here is your own code with some minor tweaks mentioned above:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("file:///D:/blackhole/print.html")
  parent_han  = driver.window_handles
  driver.find_element_by_link_text('Print').click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  all_han = driver.window_handles
  new_han = [x for x in all_han if x != parent_han][0]
  driver.switch_to.window(new_han)
  driver.close()
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium Switch Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs/53692407#53692407)

Comment: +1 Thanks Deb for detailed answer and suggestions. Somehow switch_to_window did not show deprecated warning in my code.

Comment: @Nutan Phasing out the deprecated methods and implementing newly developed methods is a part of _best practice_ every developer should follow. However, unless _removed_ deprecated methods should continue to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`driver.close()` only closes the current window.
To close all Windows and quit the webdriver, call `driver.quit()` instead.

Comment: Thanks though I want to close only newly opened window. Main window shall remain open.