# Windows Handling Closes the whole browser if i try to close the current window in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, window-handles

Am currently using windows handling for opening the map direction in the new window and after it opens  i will be closing the child window, which is opened and do the remaming work in the code.But it is closing the whole browser, while debugging it is working correctly , but while running the code, am Getting the error as,

Error - `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed`

Down i have attached the code,

```
   ##Clicking on The Map Image
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]").click()
            ##Setting up an Window Handle to get the size.
            handels =self.driver.window_handles
            size = len(handels)
            """
            The Below For Loop, We are using For Handling The Mutilple Windows,
            Which are opened in the Browser.
            """

            for length in range(size):
                driver.switch_to.window(handels[length])
                print(self.driver.title)
                time.sleep(3)
                if length == 1:
                    driver.close()
```

Where i have done the error i dunno. please sort me out.

Comment: So you're clicking something that opens new window and you want to close main window and switch to new window to continue your actions, right?

Comment: you are Right, am Clicking on Something that will open in new window and i will close that window which i was clicked, and contuine my actions, i Hope you got that! @Andersson

Comment: Post the URL that you are using and the manual scenario that opens a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to close new window and switch back to main window

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Get current window
current = self.driver.current_window_handle
# Get current windows
handles = self.driver.window_handles
# Click button. Consider to use more reliable relative XPath instead of this absolute XPath
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]").click()
# Wait for new window
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(handles))
# Switch to new window
self.driver.switch_to.window([w for w in self.driver.window_handles if w != current][0])
# Close new window
self.driver.close()
# Switch back to main window
self.driver.switch_to.window(current)
```

Comment: it is closing the my parent Window, not  closing the window i clicked @Andersson

Comment: @koushik , OK... So I might misunderstood you... How many windows you need to handle? What is that *parent* and what is *the window you clicked*? These are not the same windows?

Comment: Let Me Tell you the Secnario, I Will be going to the Locations and will be clicking on the one Map image which will open in new window, i need to close that one only . this "self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]").click()" will open in new window above i mentioned in code.

Comment: i Hope now you got right? any clarifications needed?

Comment: @koushick , hmm... so you want to close new window which opens after you made a click and get back to main window?

Answer (score 1):

In short the switching to the *new window handle* wasn't clean.

### Solution

- Always keep track of the *Parent Window* handle so you can traverse back later if required as per your usecase.
- Always use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`number_of_windows_to_be(num_windows)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.number_of_windows_to_be) before switching between *Tabs/Windows*.
- Always keep track of the *Child Window* handles so you can traverse whenever required.
- Always use *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` as [`title_contains("partial_page_title")`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.title_contains) before extracting the *Page Title*.
- Here is your own code with some minor tweaks mentioned above:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  handels_initially  = driver.window_handles
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]/img[1]").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
  handels_now =self.driver.window_handles
  new_handle = [x for x in handels_now if x != handels_initially][0]
  driver.switch_to.window(new_handle)
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.title_contains("partial_title"))
  print(self.driver.title)
  driver.close()
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium Switch Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs/53692407#53692407)

Comment: Nice Elegant Way to code,More to learn, Thanks! This Also Working. But one Doubt, Why Can't we loop throw the windows, like in my above code.?

Comment: @koushick You can't loop throw the windows like in your code as `handels =self.driver.window_handles` doesn't ensures that the items in the _List_ will be stored in a _first generated first inserted_ basis and the _List_ can be random.

Comment: Fine, now i got that, it will be not excatly identifies the List which is being stored. Thanks @DebanjanB if you found my question useful, upvote it so others might know