# How to click a browser tab to bring it to front in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Using python selenium, I did: driver.get(base_url) and it [image]

The only problem is: it went into the tab in the background(attached picture no.2), how do click on that tab which will it to the front?

Comment: Please take a look at this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690243/selenium-switch-tabs). This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's an windows handles issue.

you can have your web driver focus on second tab with the below code  :

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```